# Items in nested FlatList not getting updated when refreshing

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I have a `FlatList` with a list of sections. Some sections have nested items. For the section that has nested items I am creating a horizontal `FlatList` for those items. Some items may appear in multiple sections.

My issue is when I "like/favourite" an item, then refresh, it does not update the item which I "liked/favourited" in the other sections. It does however, update in the `<LargeVenue/>` and when I restart the app. Indicating it is working and I think there may be a problem with my code related to `React Native`

### renderItem code:

```js
    const renderItem = useCallback(({ item }) => {
      switch (item.size) {
        case "small":
          return (
            <SmallSection
              title={item.title}
              items={item.items}
              footer={item.footer}
            />
          );
        case "medium":
          return (
            <MediumSection
              title={item.title}
              items={item.items}
            />
          );
        default:
          return (
            <LargeVenue
              venue={item}
              favouriteVenue={() => favouriteVenue(item, !item.isFavourite)}
              pushVenueScreen={() => pushVenueScreen(item)}
            />
          );
        }
      }, []);
```

### MediumSection code:

```js
    export default function MediumSection({ title, items }) {
      const [venues, setVenues] = useState(items);
      const { user } = useAuth();
      const { language } = useLanguage();
      const navigation = useNavigation();
    
      const renderItem = useCallback(
        ({ item }) => {
          const updateFavourite = (isFavourite) => {
            updateFavouritesBatch(user.uid, item, !isFavourite);
            const updatedItem = { ...item, isFavourite };
            setVenues((prevState) => {
              const updatedItems = prevState.map((currentItem) => {
                if (currentItem.id === updatedItem.id) {
                  return updatedItem;
                } else {
                  return currentItem;
                }
              });
              return updatedItems;
            });
          };
    
          if (items.length === 1) {
            return (
              <SingleVenue
                venue={item}
                pushVenueScreen={() => pushVenueScreen(item)}
                favouriteVenue={() => updateFavourite(!item.isFavourite)}
              />
            );
          } else {
            return (
              <MediumVenue
                venue={item}
                pushVenueScreen={() => pushVenueScreen(item)}
                favouriteVenue={() => updateFavourite(!item.isFavourite)}
              />
            );
          }
        },
        [venues]
      );
    
      const itemSeparatorComponent = () => {
        return <View style={{ width: 10 }} />;
      };
    
      const pushVenueScreen = (venue) => {
        navigation.navigate("VenueLayout", {
          screen: "Venue",
          params: { id: venue.id, isFavourite: venue.isFavourite },
        });
      };
    
      return (
        <>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.headingContainer}
            disabled={items.length === 1}>
            <Heading
              style={styles.heading}
              numberOfLines={2}>
              {title[language]}
            </Heading>
            {items.length > 1 && <Body>All</Body>}
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <FlatList
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
            data={venues}
            renderItem={renderItem}
            horizontal
            contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainerStyle}
            ItemSeparatorComponent={itemSeparatorComponent}
            showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
            scrollEnabled={items.length > 1}
          />
        </>
      );
    }
```

### onRefresh Code:

```
    const onRefresh = useCallback(() => {
      setRefreshing(true); // setRefreshing(false) within getData completion.
      getData();
    }, []);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use extraData property of flatList to rerender updated list.